# Is Managed Identity used for more than authentication?

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-managed-identity, azure-data-lake-gen2

For accessing ADLS gen 2 containers we perform mounting in Azure Databricks with the help of a Service Principal(client Id, Tenet Id, Client secret).

Can we use User assigned managed identity to perform the mounting instead of service principal in Azure Databricks? or to simply put how to use User assigned managed identity to access ADLS containers?

I'm trying to avoid the use of Service principal and trying to use User assigned managed identity but not able to perform mounting and I'm not finding any right documentation for reference to access the ADLS containers.

Can anyone let me know a solution for How to use User Assigned Managed Identity to access  ADLS Container?

Please let me know if this is not the right approach to use managed identity.

Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, databricks does not support managed identity: saying that you can't assign a managed identity to azure databricks

Answer (score 0):

As per [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identities-status), only the following services can use managed identities to access other services.

API Management
Application Gateway
Azure App Configuration
Azure App Services
Azure Arc enabled Kubernetes
Azure Arc enabled servers
Azure Automanage
Azure Automation
Azure Batch
Azure Blueprints
Azure Cache for Redis
Azure Container Instance
Azure Container Registry
Azure Cognitive Services
Azure Data Box
Azure Data Explorer
Azure Data Factory
Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1
Azure Data Share
Azure DevTest Labs
Azure Digital Twins
Azure Event Grid
Azure Image Builder
Azure Import/Export
Azure IoT Hub
Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)
Azure Logic Apps
Azure Log Analytics cluster
Azure Machine Learning Services
Azure Managed Disk
Azure Media services
Azure Monitor
Azure Policy
Azure Purview
Azure Resource Mover
Azure Site Recovery
Azure Search
Azure Service Fabric
Azure SignalR Service
Azure Spring Cloud
Azure SQL
Azure SQL Managed Instance
Azure Stack Edge
Azure Static Web Apps
Azure Stream Analytics
Azure Synapse
Azure VM image builder
Azure Virtual Machine
Azure Virtual Machines
Azure Web PubSub Service

Unfortunately, Azure Databricks cannot use managed identity to access other services. But you can raise feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/2efba7dc-ef24-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0)